# Why does an HttpRequest to a css file returns also the .scss file?

Tags: html, css, sass, httprequest

I am using Sass to render my CSS files and i have noticed that when debugging with Edge i get lots of HTTP404: NOT FOUND exceptions(Not getting the same errors with Chrome).
When looking at the error message i see that when trying to retrieve the .CSS file, the response also sends the .scss file in the 'sources' section of the response body.

How can i fix this and make this error go away?

Comment: Sounds like it's something to do with your sourcemap config.

Comment: Where can i view/Edit the sourcemap config?

Comment: Probably in your gulp/webpack file(s).